# input text/textarea size

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, forms, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

form:

```
<form id="defineForm" method="POST" action="api/test">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Generale</legend>
        <input type="text" name="id" size="60" maxlength="60"/>
        <input type="text" name="descr" size="60"/>
        <textarea name="longDescr" cols="62" rows="10"></textarea>
```

using `cols="62"` for "longDescr" and `size="60"` for "id" produces area of the **same width** (oh! oh! surprise!) on IE8:

```
   [ text       ] 
   [ text       ]
   [ textarea   ]
   [            ]
```

Of course these values proceduces another result on Firefox (two different width as I expect), something like:

```
   [ text       ] 
   [ text       ]
   [ textarea      ]
   [               ]
```

How can I force the same width, at least on IE7/8 and Firefox, of input text and textareas?

**EDIT**

I'm using this CSS:

```
input, textarea {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 20ex;
}
```

but it doesn't works on firefox

Comment: The reason it's not working is that <input>s and <textarea>s use different fonts by default. See my answer for more details.

Comment: using font: inherit; solved my problem on firefox, thanks very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the CSS `width` style to give them a physical width in real units:

```
#id, #longDescr {
    width: 60ex;
}
```

You'll need to give them each an `id` attribute to match their `name`s before that works.

Unless you give them a width in pixels, you'll also need to ensure that they're using the same font, which by default they won't on many browsers.  The easiest way is like this:

```
#id, #longDescr {
    font: inherit;
    width: 60ex;
}
```

which will make them use the same font as the rest of the page, but obviously you might want to specify the exact font to use.

Answer (score 1):

Create an ID for each field, then using CSS set the `display` to `inline-block`, and the `width` to whatever you want.

I'd also suggest adding `<label>` elements for the fields. I believe this will give you a browser-supported tooltip, as well as better usability for a screenreader.